# How to use Github Android project in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I have just started learning Android programming. One of my school assignment requires me to prepare Android app wherein website is opened.

I saw many projects links which go to Github zip file, but how to use them in Android Studio?

Comment: What is Github zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go to Android Studio:

```
File > New > Project from Version Control > Github
```

and you past a Git link like this one: https://github.com/FredJul/Flym.git

Or, you can unzipe the file and :

```
File > New > Import project
```